# Create a curve using Flutter: Bezier Curve

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bezier

I've created a custom clipper Bezier curve in flutter however the curve I've created is not smooth(No curve).

What I have now is this.

[image]

**Code**

```
  class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();

    path.lineTo(0, size.height) ;
    var firstEndPoint = new Offset(0,size.height);
    var firstControlPoint = new Offset(35,size.height* 7/10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy, firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy);
    
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height* 7/10);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

I want that corner to be a smooth curve and I've tried changing values but failed to do so.

What needs to be changed in the code to get the proper result ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A picture would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you perhaps want this? If not, please attach a picture of what you want to achieve in the question.

[image: demo]

Also, I cleaned up your coding style a bit to make it more like dart:

```
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final firstEndPoint = Offset(10, size.height * 0.7);
    final firstControlPoint = Offset(35, size.height * 0.7);

    return Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy,
          firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.7)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks